# Childwindow WPF extended toolkit not opening

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-4.0

This is my code to open childwindow:

```
 ImageLocation location = new ImageLocation();            
            location.WindowStartupLocation = Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.WindowStartupLocation.Center;

            location.Show();
```

But the childwindow doesn't show at all.

This is my xaml for childwindow:

```
<xctk:ChildWindow x:Class="CXLocalSearch.Dialogs.ImageLocation"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Caption="Image Path"
                  xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
       Height="64" Width="400">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="63.95"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Margin="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Image Path"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,2,0,2" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBox x:Name="txtPath" Margin="0,2" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnSave" Content="Save" Click="btnSave_Click"  Width="60" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</xctk:ChildWindow>
```

Could anybody please clarify what the issue is?

Comment: any error message or something?

Comment: @roqz: No, nothing happens. It never shows.

Comment: have you tried other values for WindowStartupLocation?

Comment: @Jehof: Yes, I removed that line. Still nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, you've separated your `ChildWindow` into a separate control. That's fine, but it needs to be hosted inside a primary window in order to ever become visible. Start with the simplest thing possible:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="...">Click to Show</Button>
        <xctk:ChildWindow x:Name="childWindow">
            <TextBlock>Hello!</TextBlock>
        </xctk:ChildWindow>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I think you'll find this works fine (assumes event hookup), so take it from there.

Comment: "That's fine, but it needs to be hosted inside a primary window in order to ever become visible" Can you please give example of this? I have same scenario i am opening child window from Class file.